# Magento 2: Update the Add to Cart button

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend

I've updated the `magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js` file and have saved it in the `VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/web/js/` folder. Unfortunately, I don't think I've saved it in the correct folder, as I'm not seeing the updates on the frontend?

Which folder should it be saved to?

Answer (score 0):

Your path is correct.
You just have to deploy your files using below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove `var` folder from root.After do this You have display changes in frontend.
Don't forgot to clean browser cache to see effect.